# Calling SetWindowPos yields "invalid window handle"

Tags: winapi, assembly, x86, masm, masm32

I have too much time on my hands and decided to write a simple program in MASM32 for no good reason. However, I can't get my SetWindowPos call to the WinApi to work. Here's the relevant code bit:

```
invoke GetForegroundWindow
mov ecx,eax
invoke GetWindowLong, ecx, GWL_EXSTYLE
AND eax,WS_EX_TOPMOST   ; check if window-
.if eax==0              ; is already on top
    mov edx,HWND_TOPMOST; nope, make it on top
.else
    mov edx,HWND_NOTOPMOST; yes, make it not on top
.endif
push ecx    ; window handle
push edx    ; placement handle
push edi    ; edi=0, someone told me this is faster
push edi
push edi
push edi
push 0043h  ; SWP_SHOWWINDOW | SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_NOMOVE
call SetWindowPos
cmp eax,0
jne mLoop1  ; jump to message loop
invoke HandleError, addr appname ; make message box with error message
; ^^^^^^^^ this shows "Invalid Window Handle"
jmp mLoop1  ; jump to message loop
```

I'm sure I'm missing somehting very obvious, but with my limited knowledge of assembly I have no idea what.

Comment: you push arguments to stack in reverse order. so from your code window handle is `0043h` of course invalid

Comment: Even when I switch the order, I get the same error. I had no idea that I was pushing in reverse though, so thank you for that!

Comment: Probably `GetWindowLong` overwrites value in `ecx` (not sure if invoke directive preserves registers in masm or not). Try using some non-volatile register (like `ebx` or `esi`, etc. or memory variable) to preserve window handle between invokes

Comment: Solved. I had tried with memore variables before, but I guess that failed due to the wrong ordering. Thanks a ton!

Comment: Try some debugging. Check what you actually put on the stack.